# Possible to control garage door with Garmin IQ?

Tags: bluetooth, garmin

I'd like my Fenix 3 to do the following:

1. Trigger = hold down start button (i.e. shortcut)
2. Send message via BT or WiFi to a server (Linux or Windows or Arduino or whatever)
3. I'll take care of the message and open/close my garage door.

After a bike tour I'd like to easily and safely open my garage door. I have a VmWare server running at home. I could use one of the machines on this server to listen to the messages or I could set up an Arduino or similar.

The main question is: Can I write an IQ app that utilizes the shortcut concept on the clock, i.e. triggered by long click on start or lap button?

***Clarification***: There seems to be some kind of global actions for long press. I can for example assign "Save position" to long press on start/stop. This works even from inside of other apps.

Can the clock communicate with sensors (i.e. Arduino or other BT client) even if not in training mode?

***Clarification***: I need to communicate directly with my Arduino via Bluetooth, i.e. not via my iPhone.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes

Long answer: If you record the time a keydown event comes in, and then check for a "long" press when the key is let up based on the time difference, you can fake it. There is not an event for a long press of a physical key though. I am also pretty sure your app needs to be the current one for this to work.

Link to the InputDelegate event options: http://developer.garmin.com/downloads/connect-iq/monkey-c/doc/Toybox/WatchUi/InputDelegate.html

As for the sensors question, I am not sure exactly what you are asking. Your app can do whatever you want, and it is my understanding that only one app will be running at a time.

Disclaimer: Thus far I have only been working with the emulator, I'm still waiting for my watch to get here.

Comment: I need to pair the watch with my bluetooth client (probably Arduino) so I can communicate directly with it even if I don't have my phone nearby (i.e. connected to watch)

Comment: Ahh, I see. You might try [Communications::transmit](http://developer.garmin.com/downloads/connect-iq/monkey-c/doc/Toybox/Communications.html#transmit-instance_method). That should allow you to send arbitrary content over BLE.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write anything that hijacks user input events from another active application (including the watch face). You could make your own watch face, but it wouldn't have the ability to send network messages and it has only one way to accept user input (the look-at-watch gesture).

This is something that you can do pretty easily from a watch-app or a widget. Assuming that your fenix3 is connected to your phone via bluetooth, you can send http get requests as you see fit.

I've written a simple app that I call GIFTTT that uses the IFTTT Maker channel to open/close my garage door (and all sorts of other things).

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was hoping that I could register an action to be selectable for the shortcut keys. Long press on Start/Stop or Back/Lap seems to be global, but the UI only lets the user select among a few actions. These shortcuts works from anywhere.